# Rotating image via css, image keeps vertical space

Tags: css

I have vertical image and I rotate them 90 degrees. However the height space is kept keeping the images vertically spaced apart.  The images are 90 x 300.  The images are rotated but they keep the 90 pixel space.  How do I get rid of the vertical space.

```
.rotateimg {
transform: rotate(90deg); /* Equal to rotateZ(45deg) */
}
```

Comment: alike position relative and coordonates, elements are only move at screen, but they keep using there initial space in the flow.

Comment: Can you add images to show what you mean?

Comment: Please make a JSFIDDLE of the problem

Comment: I can't create a link but the collaborate link works https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4kzN9NaOdh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set negative margin. For example:

```css
.rotateimg {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

Comment: I tried the margin-top but it breaks it from the table.

Comment: @newdeveloper negative and positive margins needs to be tuned to the size of your image . example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWmwKWO